# How to transpose a dataset in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, transpose

For example, i would like to transform:

```
Name,Time,Score
Dan,68,20
Suse,42,40
Tracy,50,38
```

Into:

```
Name,Dan,Suse,Tracy
Time,68,42,50
Score,20,40,38
```

**Edit:** The original question used the term "transpose" incorrectly.

Comment: The word you are looking for is pivot, as opposed to transpose.

Comment: What have you tried? Is this homework? WHY do you want to transform it from something usual to something weird?

Comment: lol. i wish i were back to the times of hw

Comment: @zr:  I'm with you.  We need a "wish-it-was-homework" tag in SO. :-)

Comment: I don't think transpose is incorrect here, personally. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Comment: @chmullig: ??? matrix transposition is EXACTLY what the OP wants. "pivot" is not the word anyone should be looking for.

Comment: @John Machin - I agree. I was disagreeing with @Slomojo. Should have phrased it better.

Comment: @chmullig: looks like I missed the "in" in incorrect ... I'm not usually fazed by double negatives; I'm the guy who writes `not not x` instead of `bool(x)` :-)

Comment: Nor am I usually not unfazed by double negatives.

Comment: Excel calls this operation "transpose". And it is a reflection in the diagonal, top-left to bottom-right, line as Wikipedia states. Why isn't it a transposition?

Comment: Yes: it is transposition. But WHY is it going from row-orientation to column-orientation... and more importantly: why do all tutorials for CSV data perform this transpose... and then fail to tell you how to get ROWS of data into your model? I have spent 2 days trying to get CSV data into a model - it should not be so hard, or so obscure.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If the whole file contents fits into memory, you can use

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
a = izip(*csv.reader(open("input.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb")).writerows(a)
```

You can basically think of `zip()` and `izip()` as transpose operations:

```
a = [(1, 2, 3),
     (4, 5, 6),
     (7, 8, 9)]
zip(*a)
# [(1, 4, 7),
#  (2, 5, 8),
#  (3, 6, 9)]
```

`izip()` avoids the immediate copying of the data, but will basically do the same.

Comment: That's very slick. You might explain what you're doing though, since it's probably not intuitive to someone unfamiliar with izip and python iterables.

Comment: @chmullig: Added and explanatory example.

Comment: If the whole file _doesn't_ fit in memory add more memory

Comment: +1. BTW, it looks like the manual needs updating "If the syntax *expression appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to a sequence" ... csv.reader() doesn't evaluate to a sequence.

Comment: I've never seen the * symbol being used this way in python before, any links where I can find documentation for it?

Comment: @Tony: In the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: @xApple: As long as all your lines have the same number of items, this will work.  If you have lines with different numbers of columns, transposition is rather meaningless anyway.

Comment: After investigation, it was a buffering and cache issue with the file objects. Sorry.

Comment: Holy wow.  Two years on, I learned more about unpacking and zip from reading this answer (found on a google search whildst trying to quick-hack around a stupid excel bug) than in all previous deliberate study.  super-slick, much respect.

Comment: numpy with it transpose method

Answer (score 18):

Transfer from `input.csv` to `output.csv`. Pandas can also help.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('input.csv', header=None).T.to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Excellent one-liner.

Comment: Saved the day, @anton-tarasenko ! I still wonder why `csv.writerows(my_list)` cannot do what I need it to. Instead I am having to do `csv.writerow(my_list)` then use your stransposing one-line to get my one row to become multiple rows. Crazy!

Answer (score 5):

Same answer of nosklo (all credits to him), but for python3:

```
from csv import reader, writer 
with open('source.csv') as f, open('destination.csv', 'w') as fw: 
    writer(fw, delimiter=',').writerows(zip(*reader(f, delimiter=',')))
```

Comment: Needs `open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as fw` or it's double spaced.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import izip
from csv import reader, writer

with open('source.csv') as f, open('destination.csv', 'w') as fw:
    writer(fw, delimiter=',').writerows(izip(*reader(f, delimiter=',')))
```

Comment: -1 If Python 2.x, should use binary mode on both files. If Python 3.x, should use newline='' on both files. Also: `delimiter=','` is the default.

Answer (score 1):

If `lines` is the list of your original text than it should be

```
for i in range(1,len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].split(',')

new_lines = []
for i in range(len(lines[0])):
    new_lines.append("%s,%s,%s" % (lines[0][i], lines[1][i], lines[2][i]))
```

or use `csv` Python module - http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

_mat = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
_mat = _mat[_mat.columns[0:3]].values
_t_mat = np.transpose(_mat)
```

Result:

> - Input matrix is : [[1 2 3]  [4 5 6]]
> - the output is: [[1 4]  [2 5]  [3 6]]

Answer (score 0):

Read the CSV into `pandas` data frame, pandas has build in function for transpose which can be invoked as below.

```
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv("test.csv", skiprows=1)
# use skiprows if you want to skip headers
df_csv = pd.DataFrame(data=csv)
transposed_csv = df_csv.T
print(transposed_csv)
```