# How to consistently handle Excel boolean with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, boolean

I'm have an Excel file where the first column is:

[image]

(where TRUE/FALSE are Excel's boolean type or whatever Excel calls them)

I'm reading this file with `python` 3.6, `pandas` 1.0.3 and `xlrd` 1.2.0:

```
dat = pandas.read_excel('simple.xlsx', engine= 'xlrd', header= None)
```

The TRUE/FALSEs seem to be converted in an inconsistent way:

```
print(list(dat.iloc[:,0]))

['col1', 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, False, 1]
```

TRUE has been converted to 1 and FALSE to `False`. This means I cannot tell whether 1 is actually the number 1 or `True`.

Is there a way to tell `pandas.read_excel` to consistently convert TRUE to `True` and FALSE to `False`?

(NB I'm using xlrd rather then openpyxl since xlrd is supported by more versions of pandas - I'm happy to switch to openpyxl if that helps here...)

Comment: Seems like you don't want `header=None` since `'col1'` is now considered a value. Either way you can add `dtype=object` as an argument to `read_excel` or if you have the headers better to do `dtype={'col1': object}` so it only casts that column to object.

Comment: I actually just tried: `dtype={'col1': 'object'}, true_values=['TRUE'], false_values=['FALSE']`, doesn't seem to work, still casts `TRUE` to `1`, weird.

Comment: Weird, maybe they are strings then? When I made a sample FALSE was converted to 0, unlike the behavior they are seeing, and then `dtype=object` worked as expected.

Comment: yea, try it without the true or false values options. read it in with ALollz suggestion of just dtype and see if it works

Comment: For the record, the example I posted is a dummy file with nothing else than the data in the screenshot. Created on Ubuntu 16 with OO Calc

Comment: Can you try with exactly the same excel file as OP? @ALollz

Comment: Perhaps my excel is outdated, but when I fill a cell with TRUE, it is centered, not right aligned in the cell.

Comment: Seemingly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661980/pandas-read-excel-sometimes-incorrectly-reads-boolean-values-as-1s-0s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really answering the question but that's how I resolved it. Basically, I needed an Excel to csv exporter and I hoped to get away with a few lines of pandas.

I ended up writing my own [excelToCsv](https://github.com/dariober/excelToCsv) with Java and the POI library which seems much more sophisticated than xlrd, openpyxl etc...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, replacing TRUE into True in excel doesn't work, also problems with date formats (but that is easier to handle in pandas).

Save the file it as .csv, then replace the duty **in a text-editor**.

I just did the replacing in pandas with the apply method, but I think it would have been much easier to just do it in a text-editor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `pd.read_excel()`, I have readapted the method in the openpyxl documentation which is by using `openpyxl.load_workbook()`:

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html#converting-a-worksheet-to-a-dataframe

The readapted snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook(filename=XLS_FILE, data_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheet7']

data = ws.values
cols = next(data)
data = list(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Note that I am using the option `data_only=True` to read the calculated cell values, because I have formulas in my sheet, but it is not necessary if the values are literal. Whereas, `pd.read_excel()` reads the calculated cells by default.

If you have mixed numeric, string, and boolean values, this method preserves the booleans. For example:

[image: example from Excel sheet]

With this example, the snippet provides this result:

```
print(df)
    col1   col2
0      1  alpha
1      2   beta
2      3      1
3      6      2
4   True      3
5  False  False
6   True   True
```