# Writing in a csv column by column and not by row

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, header

I want to fiil a csv with result of my code at each loop. I want to write by column and not by row. All the tentatives i tried seems to not work. Any idea about how can I solve the problem.
I want each line to appear in the column "line" and the tag in the column "tag"  and so on.
code :

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs 
import re
import csv
import numpy as pd
from itertools import islice
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd
try:
    import treetaggerwrapper
    print("import TreeTagger OK")
except:
    print("Import TreeTagger pas Ok")


with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    #csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter= ';')
    columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list*
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    for row in csv_reader:
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value 
            columns[k].append(v)
            #print(dict(row))
Verbatim = columns['Verbatim']
#print(Verbatim)
print("reading  ok")

tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='fr')
list_Pos = []
header = ['line','tags','subl1','subl2']
with open('customers.csv', 'wt') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    csv_writer.writerow(header)
    for line in Verbatim:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
    #print(ligne);ligne = re.sub('<iwer>.*?</iwer>', '', ligne);ligne = re.sub('<iwer>.*?<iwer>', ''ligne);ligne = ligne.replace("â€™","'")
    #write header
with open('customers.csv', 'a') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for line in Verbatim:
        tags = tagger.tag_text(line)
        csv_writer.writerow(tags)
        list_Pos.append(tags)
#print(list_Pos)
print("treetagger ok")


# RÃ©cupÃ©ration des lemmes
with open('customers.csv', 'a') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    lemme_list = [[i.split('\t')[-1] for i in subl]for subl in list_Pos]    
    for subl in lemme_list:
        csv_writer.writerow(subl)
with open('customers.csv', 'a') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    Lemme_filtre =[]
    stopWords = set(stopwords.words('french'))
    Lemme_filtre = [[w.lower() for w in subl if w.isalnum() if w not in stopWords]for subl in lemme_list]
    for subl in Lemme_filtre:
        csv_writer.writerow(subl)
```

this is the output :

It seems to be writing by row and not by column

```
"line","tags","subl1","subl2"

"J","e"," ","s","u","i","s"," ","m","o","n","t","e","r","l","a"," ","b","o","u","l","a","n","g","e","r","i","e"

"T","u"," ","e","s"," ","m","é","c","h","a","n","t"

"J","e"," ","t","e"," ","h","a","i","s"," ","e","t"," ","l","a"," ","F","o","r","e","t"," ","e","n","c","h","a","n","t","é","e"," ","e","s","t"," ","b","e","l","l","e"," ","d","e"," ","m","i","l","l","e","s"," ","f","a","u","x"," ","e","t"," ","l","e","s"," ","j","e","u","n","e","s"," ","f","i","l","l","e","s"," ","s","o","n","t"," ","a","s","s","i","s","e","s"," ","a","u"," ","b","o","r"," ","d","e"," ","l","a"," ","m","e","r"

"J","e"," ","n","e"," ","C","o","m","p","r","e","n","d","s"," ","p","a","s"," ","l","a"," ","v","i","e"," ","e","t"," ","j","e"," ","s","u","i","s"," ","p","e","r","d","u","e"," ","a","i","d","e"," ","m","o","i"," ","s","t","p"," ","m","a","m","a","n"," ","j","e"," ","s","u","i","s"," ","p","e","r","d","u","e"," ","t","u"," ","e","s"," ","m","a"," ","s","e","u","l","e"," ","a","m","i","e"," ","e","t"," ","j","e"," ","t","'","a","i","m","e"

"Je PRO:PER je","suis   VER:pres    suivre|être","monterla  NOM monterla","boulangerie  NOM boulangerie"

"Tu PRO:PER tu","es VER:pres    être","méchant  NOM méchant"

"Je PRO:PER je","te PRO:PER te","hais   VER:pres    haïr","et   KON et","la DET:ART le","Foret  NAM Foret","enchantée   VER:pper    enchanter","est VER:pres    être","belle    ADJ beau","de   PRP de","milles NOM mille","faux    ADJ faux","et   KON et","les    DET:ART le","jeunes ADJ jeune","filles  NOM fille","sont    VER:pres    être","assises  VER:pper    asseoir","au    PRP:det au","bor    NOM bor","de    PRP de","la DET:ART le","mer    NOM mer"

"Je PRO:PER je","ne ADV ne","Comprends  VER:pres    comprendre","pas    ADV pas","la    DET:ART le","vie    NOM vie","et    KON et","je PRO:PER je","suis   VER:pres    suivre|être","perdue    VER:pper    perdre","aide   NOM aide","moi  PRO:PER moi","stp   VER:simp    stp","maman NOM maman","je  PRO:PER je","suis   VER:pres    suivre|être","perdue    VER:pper    perdre","tu PRO:PER tu","es VER:pres    être","ma   DET:POS mon","seule ADJ seul","amie NOM ami","et    KON et","je PRO:PER je","t' PRO:PER te","aime   VER:pres    aimer"

"je","suivre|être","monterla","boulangerie"

"tu","être","méchant"

"je","te","haïr","et","le","Foret","enchanter","être","beau","de","mille","faux","et","le","jeune","fille","être","asseoir","au","bor","de","le","mer"

"je","ne","comprendre","pas","le","vie","et","je","suivre|être","perdre","aide","moi","stp","maman","je","suivre|être","perdre","tu","être","mon","seul","ami","et","je","te","aimer"

"monterla","boulangerie"

"être","méchant"

"haïr","foret","enchanter","être","beau","mille","faux","jeune","fille","être","asseoir","bor","mer"

"comprendre","vie","perdre","aide","stp","maman","perdre","être","seul","ami","aimer"
```

Comment: please consider reading the working of your OS and the file pointer so that you'll know what complexity you are adding in computation.

Comment: If the CSV file is not too large then it would be easiest to write the CSV file first using rows, then transpose it to columns [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4869245/2269232)

Comment: @Gahan I do not understand what you mean