# Retype csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I got a csv file with two headers, and I don't know how to express it either, I pasted it and this is what it looks like, I need to reorder it to be a normal csv file,No information in "age" key，I just want to retrieve "name" and "age"，I need to output "first_name","last_name","age". And use "first_name","last_name","age" as the title，

```
"ID","meta_key","meta_data"
1,"nickname","dale ganger"
2,"first_name","ganger"
3,"last_name","dale"
4,"age",
5,"sex","F"
6,"nickname","dale ganger"
7,"first_name","ganger"
8,"last_name","dale"
9,"age",
10,"sex","F"
11,"nickname","dale ganger"
12,"first_name","ganger"
13,"last_name","dale"
14,"age",
15,"sex","F"
```

I used this code, but it doesn't merge the headers,

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('input.csv', header=None).T.to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

output

```
ID,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
meta_key,nickname,first_name,last_name,age,sex,nickname,first_name,last_name,age,sex,nickname,first_name,last_name,age,sex
meta_data,dale ganger,ganger,dale,,F,dale ganger,ganger,dale,,F,dale ganger,ganger,dale,,F
```

The final look I want

```
nickname,first_name,last_name,age,sex
dale ganger,ganger,dale,,F
dale ganger,ganger,dale,,F
dale ganger,ganger,dale,,F
```

Comment: so you want to check if each key has a value?

Comment: I just want to retrieve "name" and "age"

Comment: can you add your code to the post (the code you used to print this output)

Comment: Definitely question is not clear, being said that; you can read your csv using pandas. `import pandas as pd` and `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`. It will handle headers for you, then you can do your manipulations. Because what you have pasted seems a transposed version of column names: meta_key, nickname, first_name, last_name, age, sex

Comment: What you have _is_ a normal CSV file. Did you want to _transpose_ your csv file so that the rows are columns? Please show your expected output.

Comment: I need to output "first_name","last_name","age". And use "first_name","last_name","age" as the title

Comment: @PranavHosangadi  ok, i updated the question, you can check it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869189/how-to-transpose-a-dataset-in-a-csv-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```py
df_csv = pd.DataFrame('data.csv')

df = df_csv.drop('ID', axis=1).transpose()
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1: , :].reset_index(drop=True)
df = df[['first_name', 'last_name', 'age']]
```

to replicate everything:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'meta_key': ['nickname', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'sex'],
        'meta_data': ['dale ganger', 'ganger', 'dale', '', 'F']}
df_csv = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df_csv) # before change

df = df_csv.drop('ID', axis=1).transpose()
df.columns = df.iloc[0] # or use below
# df.columns = ['nickname', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'sex']
df = df.iloc[1: , :].reset_index(drop=True)
df = df[['first_name', 'last_name', 'age']]
print(df) # after change
```

output is:

|  | first_name | last_name | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ganger | dale |  |

**I see you changed your question, now the data is repeating every 5 rows. Then I would do this below:**

```py
df = pd.read_csv('unstructured.csv')

# create a dictionary to store the data each iteration
data_dict = {'nickname': [], 'first_name': [], 'last_name': [], 'age': [], 'sex': []}

for i in range(0, len(df), 5):
    data_dict['nickname'].append(df['meta_data'][i])
    data_dict['first_name'].append(df['meta_data'][i+1])
    data_dict['last_name'].append(df['meta_data'][i+2])
    data_dict['age'].append(df['meta_data'][i+3])
    data_dict['sex'].append(df['meta_data'][i+4])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

print(new_df)
```