# How do I loop through one row of a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV File, and I want to loop through the values of one column (in python). The csv file has 5000 rows and two columns. How do I loop through only the first column and not the second?

I tried doing

```
for row in df
for column in row
```

But this didn't work. How do I fix it?

Comment: Transpose it  - [How to transpose a dataset in a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869189/how-to-transpose-a-dataset-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: Your title says row, shouldn't it say column?

Comment: If you only want one column, why are you looping through all the columns? You seem to have made the same mistake in the code as you did in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `pandas` to do this...something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('blah.csv')
column = df['column_name'] # column_name is the name of the column
for row in column:
    print row
```

Answer (score 0):

For eaxmple your df looks like this

```
  column1    column2
0   name1   Address1
1   name2  Adsdrees2
2   name3   Address3
```

To access column1

```
for item, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['column1'])
```

prints #

```
name1
name2
name3
```

Comment: Why not just `for val in df['column1']`? it will be much faster

Comment: Agree @DeepSpace using `for val in df['column1']` snippet changes dtypes for some cases. To preserve `dtype ` and safly itterrate `df.iterrows()`  is recommonded sometimes [Ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) check last 2 lines

Comment: That reference only compares `iterrows` to `itertuples`. Anyway, OP didn't mention any importance to dtypes, so I'd at least mention the much faster approach